# Reading markdown file with elements separated by double line feeds

Tags: python, split, markdown, line

I have a markdown file (*.md) containing the following text:

```
Aliquam posuere

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit 
tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et

BarPlot,bar.csv, Animal, Count, Animal Facts
```

I would like to read this markdown file and obtaining a list of 3 element that are, in the original *.md file, separated by an empty line. In other words, I'd like to get the following output:

```py
result = [
    'Aliquam posuere', 
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et',
    'BarPlot,bar.csv, Animal, Count, Animal Facts'
]
```

with `len(result) = 3`.

Comment: Okay, cool. Do you have a question? What have you tried, and how did it fail to do what you want? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you have to read in the file and split at a double linebreak (out of simplicity I take a string) like this:

```
s = """Aliquam posuere

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit
tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et

BarPlot,bar.csv, Animal, Count, Animal Facts

"""

result = s.split('\n\n')
result = result [:-1]
```

You get a list of length 4 because you have a double linebreak at the end. Just remove the last item and you got your desired output:

```
result = ['Aliquam posuere',
 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit\ntempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et',
 'BarPlot,bar.csv, Animal, Count, Animal Facts']
```